# Add days to an Oracle Date in SSRS

Tags: oracle, date, ssrs-2008, bids, addition

I'm connecting to ORACLE data for SSRS purposes, using Microsoft Business Intelligence Development Studio.

I need to return data where a date is less than 15 days from today. I've tried the sql that works in ORACLE:

```
<= to_char(sysdate, ‘yyyymmdd’)-15
```

but it doesn't work in BIDS - when I move away from the filter field quotes are applied to turn the whole function into a string.

If someone can let me know the correct syntax it would be a real help.

Thanks
Neil

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try this:

```
to_char(trunc(sysdate)-15, ‘yyyymmdd’)
```

Trunc will remove the time part from your system timestamp.

Comment: Hi Mucio, I tried, but ssrs converted it into the following: = TO_CHAR(TRUNC(TO_CHAR(SYSDATE, 'J')) - 15, 'yyyymmdd'), and then returned an ORA-01481 invalid number format model error when run

Comment: Thank you - this did work when I entered it directly into the code view of BIDS, rather than the design view, which does not parse oracle SQL correctly.